# R increment vector in for-loop

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a table calles "pvalue" of 61 columns :

- the first one is the name of the sample "IdEch"
- all other columns are different pvalues named Pvalue1 to Pvalue60
  I would like to select all "IdEch" that display AT LEAST one value < 0.01

I tried by doing a for-loop on each column (that select Pvalue < 0.01)
But I don't manage to record the IdEch in a vector. I just have the number of the column...which is useless... I do not manage to find the solution....

Here is my script:

```
res = data.frame()

list_pvalue = c()

for (i in 2:ncol(pvalue)) {

  res = subset( pvalue , pvalue[,i] < 0.01 ) 

  list_pvalue = c(res$IdEch,list_pvalue)

}

list_pvalue = unique(list_pvalue)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You want to find rows for which **any** pvalues are `< 0.01`, for each row.

To do something for each row, use `apply`. To see if `any` values are true, use `any` (`?apply`, `?any`)

```
# pvalue[, -1] selects all but the first column
# pvalue[, -1] < 0.01 is a logical dataframe of TRUE/FALSE
# apply(X, 1, FUN) applys FUN to each row of X
# apply(pvalue[, -1] < 0.01, 1, any) is TRUE for each row that has a pvalue < 0.01
pvalue[apply(pvalue[, -1] < 0.01, 1, any), ] # is what you are after
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and this of @kasterma work perfectly. I have chosen yours because running time is a little bit shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Try below example

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
pvalue <- data.frame(IdEch=paste0("ID",1:10),
                     Pvalue1=runif(10,0,0.05),
                     Pvalue2=runif(10,0,0.05),
                     Pvalue3=runif(10,0,0.05),
                     Pvalue4=runif(10,0,0.05),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

pvalue
#    IdEch     Pvalue1     Pvalue2     Pvalue3     Pvalue4
# 1    ID1 0.014378876 0.047841667 0.044476966 0.048151212
# 2    ID2 0.039415257 0.022666708 0.034640170 0.045114952
# 3    ID3 0.020448846 0.033878532 0.032025341 0.034535264
# 4    ID4 0.044150870 0.028631670 0.049713489 0.039773371
# 5    ID5 0.047023364 0.005146234 0.032785290 0.001230684
# 6    ID6 0.002277825 0.044991249 0.035426523 0.023889799
# 7    ID7 0.026405274 0.012304387 0.027203301 0.037922977
# 8    ID8 0.044620952 0.002102977 0.029707101 0.010820397
# 9    ID9 0.027571751 0.016396036 0.014457987 0.015909050
# 10  ID10 0.022830737 0.047725182 0.007355682 0.011581289

pvalue[ rowSums(pvalue[,-1] < 0.01) > 1, "IdEch" ]
# [1] "ID5"
```

Comment: Very nteresting option as well. I deleted "IdEch" otherwise it was not working..:. pvalue[ rowSums(pvalue[,-1] < 0.01) >= 1, ]

Comment: @Sandrine It works with dummy data, if your data structure is different from my example, then please provide reproducible data.

Answer (score 2):

```
pvalue[-1]
```

gives the data frame without the IdEch column.  Applying `pmin` to this gives you the minimum values in each row.  If some value is less than 0.01, then the min value is.

```
do.call("pmin", pvalue[-1]) < 0.01
```

then gives you the rowindices that have small values.  So that

```
pvalue[do.call("pmin", pvalue[-1]) < 0.01]
```

should be what you want.